# How do I associate multiple users to a node?

Tags: users

Let's say we have a node as a School class, and I'd like to assign users (students) to that particular node. I have seen couple of modules (signup) or (user reference) but I'd like to make it much simpler and just assign those users to that node somehow. is there any easy way of doing this without using CCK or other modules?

Comment: You may get some better answers if you ouline a use-case describing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: if by "associate" you mean, "set the author to" then you can't do this.

Comment: No the author can remain as one user. Let's say we have a node as a School class, and I'd like to assign users (students) to that particular node. I have seen couple of modules (signup) or (user reference) but I'd like to make it much simpler and just assign those users to that node somehow. is there any easy way of doing this without using CCK or other modules?

Comment: I've done something exactly like what you're describing for a school. We ended up using a userref field provided by CCK for a number of reasons, one of them being that it is very easy to set up and maintain, especially if there's a chance the project might be handed over to another developer down the line. Is there some particular reason that you're avoiding CCK? I think we should focus on addressing that concern before prematurely suggesting an alternative solution.

Comment: It is just for this particular project we don't use CCK at all, and not intend to install it either (and for learning purpose) I'd like to do it without it.

Comment: if the reason you're avoiding CCK is because you don't know how to use it, I take it that you also can't write PHP?

Comment: Hey David, I am not sure I like your answer, if I couldn't write PHP then I wouldn't waste my time on this website would it? As I said I just don't want to use CCK FOR THE PURPOSE OF LEARNING. I'd like to learn how I can do it myself. I appreciate if you stop replying my comments, you ain't useful and are very rude as well

Comment: wasn't trying to be rude. Lots of people use Drupal who can't write PHP, it is actually quite common and depending on how comfortable you are with it, would change the advice. There is no real competitor to CCK in Drupal 6, which is why it was rolled into core for Drupal 7. If you're happy to write your own solution then you can use the drupal form API directly to get those fields on the node add/edit form. All you're really after, it seems (without any concrete use case), is to get an array of user IDs to appear when you call `node_load()`, right?

Answer (score 2):

User Reference sounds perfect for what you are trying to achieve. Not much is simpler than being able to select the users in the edit node form. Can you describe what kind of GUI you would like to use to select the use

Comment: I ideally like to implement my own GUI for that, listing all the students on one side, and give permission to tutor to select and add the ones they want to that particular class

Comment: Okay, implement your own GUI and use user reference to attach the data to the node.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you could do that with your own custom module.

Just alter node form with form_alter and add your own field (autocomplete?) which could poll users table. You also need some place to store references. Nid_uid table would do it.

On save you could save data to your table.

But as most people mentioned CCK user reference field would be the best bet.